# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops

HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure when running on dotnet3 core on a remote system, even though it works locally.

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)

My csproj is below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers" Version="3.0.0-preview3-19153-02" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet" Version="2.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.Entityframeworkcore.Mysql" Version="3.0.0-rc1.final" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="serilog.sinks.file" Version="4.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: How did you deploy the WebApp? Did you **publish** it by `dotnet publish` or just copy your project ?

Comment: FTP. The file is there but I do not understand what the mismatch is really referring to.

Comment: The build is deployed by an Azure DevOps Pipeline, not my local PC.  If I edit the web.config modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" to "AspNetCoreModule" on the server it works fine.   If I add this web.config to my build, Azure DevOps build fails with : /opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/TransformTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets(50,5): error MSB4018: System.Exception: In process hosting is not supported for AspNetCoreModule. Change the AspNetCoreModule to at least AspNetCoreModuleV2.